# RSpec mocking send_file returns error template is missing

Tags: ruby, rspec

In one of my controllers I have the following method:

```
def show
  @icon = @product.icon
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @icon.present?

  send_file File.join('public', @icon), type: 'image/png', filename: 'icon.png', x_sendfile: true
end
```

And I'm trying to test the method like so:

```
it 'it renders the icon' do
  create(:product, icon: 'icon.png')
  icon = double('icon', content_type: 'image/png', filename: 'icon.png')
  allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:send_file).and_return(icon)
  get(:show, params: { product: 'test' })
  expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to eq('image/png')
  expect(response.header['Content-Disposition']).to eq("attachment; filename=\"icon.png\"")
end
```

So the idea is to mock the response of `send_file` with the `double`.

However I get the error that the `show` template is missing for this method... so it seems it's not properly mocking out the response I want...

How do I get the `send_file` to return the mocked image as per my test?

I've also tried: `allow(controller).to receive(:render).and_return(icon)` bu this just ends up returning an empty string instead of the mocked image...

Comment: I wonder why you want to do that. Mocking `send_file` means in this context that you try to mock that method that does everything you are interested in in your expectations. That basically means you are testing your mock but not the actual behavior. What is wrong with just using the original implementation?

Comment: @spickermann Not sure I follow... Basically the icon doesn't exist (as I've mocked it out via the double) and I want to test that `send_file` when asked to return an icon that is mocked (so the same as a real icon) will be the same e.g. the content type etc... do you have an alternate solution you can show? Thanks.

Comment: I tried: `allow(controller).to receive(:render).and_return(icon)` instead... but this just renders an empty string as `text/html` so doesn't work either...

Comment: That means you actually want to mock `@product.icon` and not the method that renders the icon?

Comment: @spickermann Well I already have done. All it does is store a string of a filename location and then in the controller we pull that file from the `public` folder and use send file to send it to the browser. So I've mocked a fake icon in the factory and also as a double and I want to test that the response of the send_file is the same.

Comment: So in short the spec should be testing that if I have an icon, that the response is of a content type of image/png etc... and to do that, I need to mock the icon and allow that send_file to handle that mocked icon (but it can't look into the public folder for it as it won't exist) if that all makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with was to just add an actual image into the spec and then allow the `File` class to return it when we do the join to the public folder and then just let the `send_file` work as normal as it's now taking a real image like so:

```rb
it 'it renders the icon' do
  create(:product, icon: 'icon.png')
  allow(File).to receive(:join).and_return('./spec/support/images/example.png')
  get(:show, params: { short_code: 'abc123' })
  expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to eq('image/png')
  expect(response.header['Content-Disposition']).to eq('attachment; filename="icon.png"')
end
```